# How can I discover someone's profile id on facebook using email address?

Tags: python, facebook, email-address

I have a list of emails and want to discover the associated facebook account.
I've been trying to use graph-api in python, but i can't find the person's page link using this api. I was able to find my page's link using my facebook id...but in this case I don't have the facebook ids yet. That's why I want to get the facebook Id using email address.

I have something like that:

```
links = graph.request('/{user-id}')
```

The return is a dict where one of the keys is the link of someones profile.

So I need to find a way to link people email address with their facebook account. Does anyone know how to do this? I couldn't find this on internet.

Ty :)

Comment: No that is of course not possible.

Comment: _“So I need to find a way to link people email address with their facebook account. Does anyone know how to do this?”_ - write them an e-mail, and ask them ... :p